# What if i don't need time along with date from room database type converter

Tags: android

```
public class DateConverter {

@TypeConverter
public Date fromTimestamp(Long value) {
    return value == null ? null : new Date(value);
}

@TypeConverter
public Long dateToTimestamp(Date date) {
    if (date == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return date.getTime();
    }
}
}
```

In the above code it is giving both time and date...But if i want only date to display, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date from `Date` object to `String` and then convert the `String` (primitive) to Date. I haven't tested the code, but it should look something like this:

```
public class DateConverter {

  public static Date toDate(String dateString){
     if(timestamp == null)
         return null;
     return new Date(dateString);
  }

  public static String toTimestamp(Date date){
      SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");        
      return dateTimeFormat.format(date);
  }
}
```